Finding the resistance to turn both diodes on

For part (a) I got \$ I_x = .93 \, mA \$ and \$V_x = 5.58 \, V \$ which aligns with my professors answers.
However for part (b), I am confused on the correct approach.
To preface, I simulated this circuit on CircuitLabs and the voltage and current readings align consistent for part (a), however, no matter how small I make the resistance of \$ R_2 \$, it will not turn both diodes on.
Solutions from my professor and chegg show that:
the current, \$ I_x = \frac{10 - 0.7}{R_1 + R_2} \$
and \$ \frac{V_x}{R_2} = I_x, \; so \; V_x = \frac{9.3R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \$
they then say that \$ V_x = 2.3 \$ from \$ 3 - .7 \$ and get that \$ R_2 \$ should become \$ 1300 \, \Omega \$ . Is this the correct methodology?
My problem is that this ignores the voltage drop from \$ R_3 \$ and even when setting \$ R_2 \$ to \$ 1300 \, \Omega \$ on a simulator, it does not produce a \$ .7 \$ voltage drop across the second diode.

1300Ω is the transition point.  If you try 1250Ω in the simulator the diode should be ON.  Might depend on how you set up your simulator.  This is my setup and you can see that I(D2) (the red plot) hits zero amps when R2 is 1.3KΩ.

The trick has everything to do with that transition point.  With the PWL diode model you're using, the "turn-on" corner is a bit strange.  At the exact corner, you can think of the diode like it's both ON (voltage drop = 0.7V) and OFF (zero current through it) at the same time.  The zero current is why there's no drop across R3, hence the 2.3V.  Here is a plot of Vx where you can see the effect of the corner.  To be more exact, the value of R2 should be 1314Ω.

https://imgur.com/a/X7PWzk1
Here is my simulation using CircuitLabs using a resistance of 100 $ \Omega $ . Here it shows that the voltage drop of the diodes are .6V, so is that close enough for this simulator? Is anything wrong with my circuit configuration? Is this simulator just not precise? I am thinking of downloading LTSpice instead.

You did not set up the simulation to match the circuit in the question. You need to pick the diode symbol that has the word IDEAL written under it and then change its V_D parameter to 0.7 V. This would be equivalent to the .model statement you see in my LTspice screenshot. If you pick a PN junction diode like the 1N4148, it follows the Shockley diode equation (an exponential) and not the PWL model I linked to above. The Shockley equation is more accurate to real life but needs a simulator to find the solution numerically. PWL model is used because it’s easier to calculate by hand.

@Ste
Ahh I see, thank you

D2 conducts when:
$$
\begin{aligned}
3 - V_X &> 0.7 \\ \\
-V_X &> 0.7 - 3 \\ \\
V_X &< 2.3 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
In other words, the point of transition between D2 conducting or not is \$V_X=2.3V\$, and D2 is "on" when \$V_X < 2.3\$. Immediately either side of that threshold \$V_X=2.3V\$, R1 has significant voltage across it, and D1 will be conducting.
You are asking for conditions under which both diodes are conducting, which is therefore the case when \$V_X<2.3V\$.
Given that by Ohm,'s law \$V_X = I_XR_2\$, the condition you are looking for becomes:
$$ I_XR_2 < 2.3 $$
You could argue that a reduction of \$R_2\$ would necessarily result in a reduction of \$V_X\$, staying within our required conditions for both diodes conducting, but this assumes that \$I_X\$ does not change, which is obviously untrue. In other words, we cannot state with certainty that decreasing \$R_2\$ will keep both diodes conducting. That may be correct (it is), but at this point it would be just an assumption, and we require a more rigourous proof.
Similarly, it would seem that increasing \$R_2\$ would increase \$V_X\$ (also true), causing D2 to switch  "off", but that's also an assumption, disregarding the consequent change in \$I_X\$.
If we accepted these assumptions as true, then we could immediately conclude that the transition threshold \$R_2=1314\Omega\$ is a maximum, and that for both diodes to remain "on", \$R_2 < 1314\Omega\$.
To be certain of this, we must show algebraically what happens to \$V_X\$ as we vary \$R_2\$. This happens in two parts, when \$V_X<2.3V\$ and when \$V_X>2.3V\$. The latter first:
When \$V_X>2.3V\$, D2 is "off", no current flows via that path, and D2/R2 can be disregarded:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_X = (10-0.7)\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}
\end{aligned}
$$
By inspection alone it's clear that increasing \$R_2\$ does indeed result in an increase of \$V_X\$.
The former condition, \$V_X<2.3V\$, requires more work, since both diodes are conducting, and \$V_X\$ will be a function of both diode currents. This is where I address the current that you mentioned was disregarded in your question:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_X &= I_XR_2 \\ \\
&= R_2\left( I_1 + I_2 \right) \\ \\
&= R_2\left( \frac{10-0.7-V_X}{R_1} + \frac{3-0.7-V_X}{R_3} \right) \\ \\
\frac{V_X}{R_2} &= \frac{9.3}{R_1} - \frac{V_X}{R_1} + \frac{2.3}{R_3} - \frac{V_X}{R_3} \\ \\
V_X \left( \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_3} \right) &= \frac{9.3}{R_1} + \frac{2.3}{R_3} \\ \\
V_X &= \frac{\frac{9.3}{R_1} + \frac{2.3}{R_3}}{\frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_3}} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
There may be an easier way, but we don't need to go any further. At this point everything on the right side is constant, except \$R_2\$, and we can see that a decrease in \$R_2\$ results in a decrease in \$V_X\$. Our first assumption was also correct.
Since under all conditions \$V_X\$ changes in the same direction as \$R_2\$, we can finally state with certainty that for both diodes to be conducting, \$R_2<1314\Omega\$.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here's a plot of diode currents as I sweep \$R_2\$ between 0Ω and 2kΩ, where you can see D2 current reaching zero at \$R_2=1314\Omega\$, while D1 also always conducts:


Ah I see, I was doing something similar where $ V_x = (I_1 + I_2) R_2 $ and trying to find a value of $ R_2 $ from there but I guess it's only used to show the relationship between $ V_x $ and $ R_2 $.
Is there something wrong with my circuit schematic using CircuitLabs? I used 100 $ \Omega $ just to make the diodes conduct but they show only ~.6 V.

@Connor You did not set up the simulation to match the circuit in the question. You need to pick the diode symbol that has the word IDEAL written under it and then change its V_D parameter to 0.7. If you pick a PN junction diode like the 1N4148, it follows the Shockley diode equation and not the PWL model your professor is using.
